# My fund lost in metamask

Tags: blockchain, metamask

can anyone go inside my Metamask without 12 seed phase? i mean i did not give it to anybody but my fund is gone. is there possibility that my wallet hacked? i already checked on Bscscan that someone sold my coin and send it to another wallet. pleas help me

Comment: Always use a hardware wallet. Also, never use a test wallet to hold mainnet assets. I learned that the hard way. You might think you're safe, but you have so many possible attack vectors when your seed or private key is stored on a device connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If tokens were transferred out of your address, there is only two options:

1. You made the transfer yourself thinking that you were doing
   something else, possibly through a phishing website; or
2. You lost your private key or it was stolen.

There are many, many ways to steal or lose a private key and without you giving more details on what you did before the tokens were stolen, we cannot pinpoint a cause.

You should check your address on bscscan and see at which address the tokens were transferred (check the last transaction). However, only the person that controls this address could send you back the tokens. If it is a scammer, it obviously will not happen.